# ratelimit bytes per second in java

Tags: java, okhttp

I am writing an integration automation test. I need to limit the bytes per second of an api request so that I can force a 408 response. I have not been able to figure out how to do that using a java client. I have looked at a few different ones with no luck, OKHttpclient, restsharp, resttemplate. I feel like a networkinterceptor for okhttpclient should be able to do it but was not able to figure out how to.

Comment: Simply use a regular HttpURLConnection and wrap the inputStream in an [LimitInputStream](https://guava.dev/releases/9.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/LimitInputStream.html) or just read the InputStream slowly.

Comment: Sorry should have said this earlier. This is for an integration automation test. I need to be able to limit it from the client side.

Comment: Client and server are connected via TCP so if you stop reading data on client side the server will stop sending after a short time until the client reads again. So it doesn't matter if you limit the speed on server or client side (as long as we are talking about more data that fits into a typical buffer used e.g. by the OS for TCP reception).